# How to find duplicate keys in localizable.strings files automatically?

Tags: xcode

When using localizable.strings with many entries in your XCode project you sooner or later may use a key more than once. Is it possible to let XCode find that case and issue a warning about it?

Apple's [Resource Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) mentions the genstrings tool, but usually you don't use that yourself in XCode. So, how can I let XCode detect duplicate keys in such files without manually running genstrings?

**Bounty note:** to earn the bounty a solution must fully integrate with XCode if it uses external resources like scripts, that is, it must work with input files given in XCode, mark a build as fail in case of duplicates and must not trigger for false positives like empty lines or comments.

Comment: I don't believe Xcode can do that, so you would probably need to write a script in Python or somesuch and call it as part of a build.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`cut -d' ' -f1 Localizable.strings | sort | uniq -c`

type this command in the terminal and you get a list saying how often each key is used.

**use -d instead of -c and you only get duplicates**

## the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=`expr $SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT - 1`
for i in $(seq 0 $c)
    do

    var="SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_$i"
    FILENAME=${!var}

    DUPES=`cut -d' ' -f1 "$FILENAME" | sort | uniq -d`

    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line == "\""* ]] ;
        then
            echo "warning: $line used multiple times -"
        fi
    done <<< "$DUPES"
done
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this can be used in the build process -- just modify filename to point at the right location

Comment: in a build process it is e.g. something like "${PROJECT_DIR}/app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings"

Comment: This is pretty cool. Can you modify the script so that it uses input files given for the script build phase and only acts on real entries of the form `key = "text";`? That way it ignores empty lines, comments and the like.

Comment: I trigger a warning [like you asked at first] but I can also make it error ;)

Comment: This great, bro! Also try this command:
    `more "$FILENAME" | tr -d ' ' | sort | uniq -d | grep -v '^$'`

Comment: @Daij-Djan - THANKS !!!! is it possible to know if there are duplicated values just like keys?

Comment: @Daij-Djan You can change the above command to get the value instead of key: `cut -d'=' -s -f2 "$FILENAME" | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: This solution would work, but it doesn't support UTF-16 encoded files (which is common for localizable strings files)

Comment: convert them to utf8!?
also ... i question if it is COMMON ;)

but I think at least the keys should map ok

Answer (score 5):

cut -d'=' -f1 Localizable.strings | sort | uniq -d

You looking phrases separated by equal sign, not a first word in each string.

Answer (score -1):

```
more Filename.strings | tr -d ' ' | sort | uniq -d | grep -v '^$'
```

Comment: This only scans for duplicate lines, not duplicate keys