# How to find duplicate keys in localisation files

Tags: ios, swift, bash

I have a couple of localisation files that I use in our project and I would like to find duplicate keys in all of them.

I have tried to use this code and it is not returning anything what could I be doing wrong:

```
folders_array=("MainProject" "StandaloneProject")

for folder in ${folders_array[*]}
do
    STRINGS_TMP="strings.tmp"
    mkdir -p "$STRINGS_TMP"
    FILES=`find "$folder" -name "Localizations*swift"`

    for FILE in $FILES
    do
        echo $FILE
        DUPES=`cut -d' ' -f1 "$FILE" | sort | uniq -d`

        while read -r line; do
            if [[ $line == "\""* ]] ;
            then
                echo "warning: $line used multiple times -"
            fi
        done <<< "$DUPES"
    done
done
```

An Example Plist file contains keys like this:

> Localizable.strings

```
"facebook_lgn_btn" = "Login";

"youTube_video" = "Sponsored";

"video_say" = "Test";
```

Comment: You mean that each File has unic keys, but since there are multiple files, you can have the same key in file1 and in file2? Also, can you use Swift instead of Bash? Since CocoaTouch has a easier method to read .strings files, and we can do scripts in Swift.

Comment: Im checking for this dublication of keys in the same file and in different files and each file should have unique keys

Comment: @kaddie, we don't know how files look. Can you show sample input and output?

Comment: Did you take your code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124530/how-to-find-duplicate-keys-in-localizable-strings-files-automatically ? What's working/not working with your current code? What's happening? Did you logs to see what's wrong? Do you find `folders`, files, etc.

Comment: yep I got the code from there I get the following error: ```MainProject/en.lproj/Localizable.strings cut: MainProject/en.lproj/Localizable.strings: Illegal byte sequence```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change:

```
FILES=`find "$folder" -name "Localizations*swift"`
```

into:

```
FILES=`find "$folder" -name "Localizable*strings"`
```

Because localizations keys, are in each `Localizable.strings` under folders such as `it.lproj`, `en.lproj`...

The script works fine if you use the correct file to check, in this case the files to check are all `Localizable.strings`.

Comment: I get the following error:
```MainProject/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
cut: MainProject/en.lproj/Localizable.strings: Illegal byte sequence```

Comment: In my project that works because the Localizable.strings I have are all well formatted, in your case if you are receiving such an error, it means that `Localizable.strings` under `MainProject/en.lproj/` might have some characters that are not UTF-8 char. Can you check if you have any weird character that is not UTF-8? That is a totally different question by the way. With that script you are able to find duplicates if you change the line as I said. Having illegal characters and checking them, might be worth a totally new question in my opinion.